# Assigning values to 2-dimensional array

Tags: vba, excel, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to get some data I input with another macro into a 2-dimensional array so I can then apply a function to that data, but no matter what I try I keep getting errors. The data includes strings and numbers. I could always just reference the cells and forget about the array, but that complicates the function. Here's my code:

(Declarations)

```
Dim nLiens As Byte, nCreditors As Byte
Dim SecurityV As Currency, ASecurityV As Currency
Const adjuster = 0.9
```

(Relevant subs)

```
Public Sub VariableDeclaration()
    nLiens = InputBox("Enter number of liens in security")
    nCreditors = InputBox("Enter number of creditors")
    SecurityV = InputBox("Enter security full value")
    ASecurityV = adjuster * SecurityV
Call ODebt
End Sub

Sub ODebt()

'
'(...)
'

Dim oDebt() As Variant
ReDim oDebt(1 To nCreditors + 1, 1 To nLiens + 1)
Dim rg As Range
Set rg = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(nCreditors + 1, nLiens + 1))
oDebt = rg.Value

MsgBox (oDebt)
'>>> ERROR: type mismatch


Call SAllocation
End Sub
```

I've tried other alternatives, such as setting the content cell by cell with two 'For' loops and `LBound` and `UBound`, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting your error not while filling, but at displaying the array.
It is not possible to just `Msgbox` an array, since `Msgbox` expects a String argument. You can, in the other hand, display specific positions (e.g. `oDebt(1,1)`).

If you want to have a look at all of its contents, either use debug mode and the `Local` window, or print it to some unused cells.

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark it as solved for future readers!

Answer (score 0):

I would copy the values from the datasheet this way:

```
Dim oDebt As Variant
Dim rg As Range

Set rg = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(nCreditors + 1, nLiens + 1))
oDebt = rg    ' get data from sheet
'... do calculations with oDebt array
rg = oDebt    ' put data on sheet
```

In words: you dimension the array automatically by assigning the range. If you need the numeric boundaries, use

```
nrows = UBound(oDebt, 1)
ncols = UBound(oDebt, 2)
```

Here you see the meaning of the dimension as well, index 1 is rows, index 2 is columns.